# compare variable value with whole string and print all value which are match with value

Tags: php

I have a string I want to compare whole string with date string which are present in the string. I 
 Retrieve the date in different variable and store it. string is separated by | means in whole
 string different string are explode from | and store in  a variable.Now i compare whole String with DATE AND echo all value with matched date means print  if date is 2014-03-10

```
   33~WRIA/16458/2007~72~RAJESH MISHRA~UNION OF INDIA THROUGH ITS SECRETARY,AND 4 
   OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:19:41 07/03/2014
   33~WRIA/29576/2007~73~SMT. MEENA YADAV AND OTHERS~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-
   10~02:19:41 07/03/2014
   33~WRIA/16458/2007~72~RAJESH MISHRA~UNION OF INDIA THROUGH ITS SECRETARY, AND 4 
   OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:56:55 07/03/2014
   33~WRIA/29576/2007~73~SMT. MEENA YADAV AND OTHERS~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-
   10~02:56:55 07/03/2014
```

And my complete string is

```
   33~WRIA/16458/2007~72~RAJESH MISHRA~UNION OF INDIA THROUGH ITS SECRETARY, AND 4 
 OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:19:41 07/03/2014|33~WRIA/29576/2007~73~SMT. MEENA YADAV AND
 OTHERS~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:19:41 
 07/03/2014|9~COPP/43/2012~19~DASAPRAKASH HOTELS AND RESORTS PVT. LTD.~M/S KUMAR
 ASHIYANA PVT. LTD.~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|9~COPP/43/2012~19~DASAPRAKASH 
 HOTELS AND RESORTS PVT. LTD.~M/S KUMAR ASHIYANA PVT. LTD.~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55
 07/03/2014|10~WRIA/50923/2012~27~LALLAN KUMAR~COAL INDIA LTD. THRU. ITS CHAIRMAN AND
 OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|10~WRIA/52176/2011~41~MANEESH THAKUR~STATE OF
 U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|10~WRIA/50923/2012~27~LALLAN 
 KUMAR~COAL INDIA LTD. THRU. ITS CHAIRMAN AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55
 07/03/2014|10~WRIA/52176/2011~41~MANEESH THAKUR~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-
 06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|33~WRIA/30565/2005~31~VIJAY PRATAP SINGH~M/S TRIVENI STRUCTURALS
 LIMITED AND ANOTHER~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|33~WRIA/30565/2005~31~VIJAY PRATAP
 SINGH~M/S TRIVENI STRUCTURALS LIMITED AND ANOTHER~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 
 07/03/2014|39~WRIC/48169/2002~2~TAUFIQ KAMAL~STATE OF U.P. THRU  SECY. HOUSING GOVT. OF
 U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55 07/03/2014|39~WRIC/48169/2002~2~TAUFIQ 
 KAMAL~STATE OF U.P. THRU  SECY. HOUSING GOVT. OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-06~02:56:55
 07/03/2014|33~WRIA/16458/2007~72~RAJESH MISHRA~UNION OF INDIA THROUGH ITS SECRETARY, 
 AND 4 OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:56:55 07/03/2014|33~WRIA/29576/2007~73~SMT. MEENA YADAV 
 AND OTHERS~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-10~02:56:55 07/03/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is probably `preg_match_all`. You can give it a pattern like `/(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})/` and it will search for values that look like dates.

Comment: sir please explain me how can i do this